# How can I do step by step debugging, or even set break point in Excel 365 Office Scirpt code?

Tags: office365, office-scripts, excel-365, ms-office-script

I have enabled Office Script, and I see AUTOMATE tab in my Excel-365. I can write a script and also see results in log and on sheet
.
But when I see the tab, or the script, **I do NOT see any way to take step by step execution, or even set a breakpoint**

So how can I do step by step execution, or even set break point in Excel 365 Office Scirpt code?

I have "Microsoft 365 Apps for business" licence.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, step-by-step debugging isn't possible with the Office Scripts Code Editor. You can use console logs to try and troubleshoot errors in your script and this documentation explains how to do so:  https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/scripts/testing/troubleshooting. If you would like to see a step-by-step debugger in the Office Scripts feature-set in the future, the Office Scripts team tracks feature requests here:  http://aka.ms/ExcelSuggestions. Feature requests are considered when we go through our planning process.

Thanks,

The Office Scripts team

Comment: Thats really sad. Even Google AppScript has rudimentary step-by-step debugger, with Step-Into, and Step-Over. And Microsoft gave excellent debugger with Edit and Continue since VB3 ie year 1991 days. So I was expecting that OfficeScript will have better debugger than Google AppScript !!!